# jQuery.load doesn't execute javascript with document.write

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I am trying to use jQuery.Load to load an ad call that has a document.write, and for some reason its not able to, or in firefox atleast, reloads the page with the entire ad.

Here is the simplified version of the code.

DynamicLoad.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.prweekus.com/js/scripts.js?3729212881" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Load of Script</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        $("#myDiv").load("source.html");
    });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<div id="slideAdUnit"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Source.html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
</script>
test
```

Once you click the button in FF the browser just waits for something to load. Any thoughts ?

Eventually I would be passing a src element in the document.write which points to our ad server.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `document.write` after the page has finished loading: it will replace the contents of the page if you do.

The easiest way to load a script dynamically with jQuery is:

```
$.getScript( url );
```

Another way is to create a new `<script>` element and add it to the document.

Answer (score 1):

[writeCapture.js](http://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture) (full disclosure: I'm the author) can solve this:

```
$("#myDiv").writeCapture().load("source.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a script block into the DOM. You can't just write it into the document like that.

Use: `$(document.createElement('script'));`, then set the attributes you require.

```
var newBlock = $(document.createElement('script'));
$(newBlock).attr('src','http://...')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue with **IE** -  it doesn't execute a script loaded using **document.write**, but creating a script **DOM** element worked perfectly fine.

In your case, if you have only one script to load in **Source.html** just modify it to dynamically create script **DOM** element. It will work in both **IE** and **FF**. But if you have multiple script files to load dynamically, you may not be able to use this technique as this technique doesn't guarantee the execution order in **IE**.

Please go to **Google** and search for "**Even Faster Websites**" and you will get a very nice article about dynamic script loading.

By the way, I don't understand why **IE** doesn't execute script loaded using **document.write.**

Also my **FF** waited for something if I use **document.write** (same thing happened to you!!). I am not sure about the reason and it could be very low-level. So, please just don't use it with **FF**. If you have already identified the reason, please share.